# Swipe is not working using Appium on Android

Tags: android, selenium, appium

```
package Android;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class driverSwipe {
AndroidDriver driver;
Dimension size;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "EUEQLZCI8TL7MFNB");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.sample.activities.SwipeListViewExampleActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("android.widget.RelativeLayout")));
}

@Test
public void swipingHorizontal() throws InterruptedException {
    //Get the size of screen.
    size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    System.out.println(size);

    //Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
    //Find startx point which is at right side of screen.
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.70);
    //Find endx point which is at left side of screen.
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.30);
    //Find vertical point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen height.
    int starty = size.height / 2;
    System.out.println("startx = " + startx + " ,endx = " + endx + " , starty = " + starty);

    //Swipe from Right to Left.
    driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, starty, 3000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //Swipe from Left to Right.
    driver.swipe(endx, starty, startx, starty, 3000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}

@Test
public void swipingVertical() throws InterruptedException {
    //Get the size of screen.
    size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    System.out.println(size);

    //Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
    //Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
    //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
    //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.
    int startx = size.width / 2;
    System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);

    //Swipe from Bottom to Top.
    driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //Swipe from Top to Bottom.
    driver.swipe(startx, endy, startx, starty, 3000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}

@AfterTest
public void End() {
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

This is my code used to develop a swiping list view app in android. I am getting an error of UnreachableBrowserException:Error and WebDriverException. Below is the logcat.

```
exception FAILED CONFIGURATION:@BeforeTestsetUp
1)org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:Error communicating with the remote browser.It may have died.
2)Caused by:org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:No command or response codec has been defined.Unable to proceed.
```

Can anybody help me what's wrong?

Comment: You have specified browsername in capabilities and also added details of native app. Decide where you are planning to test. Anyway the accepted options for browser options in android is Chrome, Chromium and Browser. Also consider dropping the hardcoded capabilites keys and use the MobileCapabilityType and AndroidMobileCapabilityType classes.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But i am running this code using appium on Emulator in ubutntu machine i  am getting error in Terminal  [ADB] Error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)

Comment: you still need to remove `browsername`. you can use appium keywords to drive the browser under an android app.